# WPF outlook integration gives me operation failed

Tags: c#, outlook, integration, backgroundworker

I am writing a small wpf application which will read top 50 emails (Just emails no other items) from users outlook through C# outlook integration.

To make my application UI responsive I am establishing MAPI connection and reading inbox folder from a background worker.

Everything works fine, but for some of the users randomly I am getting following exception.

```
The operation failed.
   at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._MailItem.get_SenderName()
   at WPFapplication.WPFOutlookView.OutlookMailItem..ctor(MailItem item)
   at WPFapplication.WPFOutlookView._getEmailsBackgroundWorker_DoWork
          (Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
```

This exception occurs very randomly and I am unable to reproduce it on my development machine.

1. Can I use background worker to establish outlook connectivity from a WPF app? (Because some online posts suggesting all outlook OOM calls must happen in outlook main thread. Is 
   it applicable even we are writing outlook addin?)
2. If so how can I make my application responsive when some user machines are with out any outlook profile setup or waiting for user to enter password?

UPDATE:
I am not trying to retrive emails unattended, just i need is irrespective of user input my application need to load its UI and it can wait to retrive emails when user entered credetials. If i call OOM in UI thread then my application's entire UI is not getting rendered until user enter credentials, that is the main reason for calling OOM in backgroundworker. My application is simple 1. a wpf view and a list box which will display top 20 emails and updates whenever user recieves a new email.2. my implementation is in my WPF view there is a backgroundworker which calls to OOM and get emails and update a list and this list is bound to list box. What changes you suggest here?

Comment: I think you truncated the exeption message

Comment: @user680370: don't try to edit answers, that's what comments are for :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution  for this issue and it is nothing to do with threading or backgroundworker. 
Actuall issue was user has 2 machines setup with same outlook profile and there is some time lag in syncing. Due to this when i am trying to read emails of a folder and user delete same email from different machine i am getting "The operation failed" exception. Resolution is i am handling com exception while reading email properties and proceeding further with rest of the emails.
For thanks for help me out.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get better view, get us the exact exception...

Answers for your question:

1) Yes, it's applicable. OOM is a STA.

2) I dont get this clear. Let me try to answer you more, if want this application to run without outlook, i doubt - in order to execute the OOM code, make sure outlook is installed in the machine. Also OOM is not suitable to work in unattended mode (without outlook profile setup/waiting for user to enter password). It's OOM's design limitation.

Hope this helps.

Comment: 1. So I cant use background theread to call OOM even in a stand alone WPF app? 2. I am using backgroundworker mainly because some users are have outlook installed but no profile is setup. I dont want my application to hang until user close outlook or profile is setup. Some times users are not entering password for long time and companing application is not rendering irrespective of input. Any code samples will be appriciated.

Comment: I again repeat the same - dont try to use threading with OOM. It's not designed to work like that. Also if you try with Network applications then you will get the same reports to enter the password/userid, again this is not possible with OOM. If you try, i recommend pls dont do that, AS OOM is not compatible to work in unattended mode/network/scheduled service. If you want to try such applications, try using MAPI (Extended MAPI/C++/Unmanaged code) - but this is not compatible with .Net framework based applications (managed code).

Comment: @dpideva1 I am not trying to retrive emails unattended, just i need is irrespective of user input my application need to load its UI and it can wait to retrive emails when user entered credetials. If i call OOM in UI thread then my application's entire UI is not getting rendered until user enter credentials, that is the main reason for calling OOM in backgroundworker.